# Trying to replace a String with a Double in an Object Array

Tags: java, arrays

The following code parses a String into String Objects and places the values in an Object array.

For any strings that represent a number it then attempts to replace the String with a Double object. However I get the following Exception:

***java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Double***

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String text = "one,two,123,123.45";

        Object[] row = text.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                row[i] = new Double( row[i].toString() );
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        System.out.println();

        for(Object o: row)
            System.out.println(o.getClass());

        //  This works, I don't see the difference?

        Object[] data = new Object[2];
        data[0] = "one";
        data[1] = "111.22";
        data[1] = new Double( data[1].toString() );

        System.out.println();

        for(Object o: data)
            System.out.println(o.getClass());
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Why does the second case work but not the first?

Comment: Oops..Had a mind crap Read the API and everything and it still didn't clue it. One of those nights.... I'll accept in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object[] row = text.split(",");` , `row` here refers to an array of type `String` but here `row[i] = new Double( row[i].toString() );` , you're assigning a a `double`

Answer (score 3):

From the docs of  [`ArrayStoreException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an ArrayStoreException:

```
  Object x[] = new String[3];
  x[0] = new Integer(0); //exception
```

In your code, you are doing the same. When you write

```
  Object[] row = text.split(",");
```

That became an array of String's. And later you are trying to do

```
row[i] = new Double( row[i].toString() );
```

Since a `String` is not `Double`, the exception thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The call `text.split(",")` returns a `String[]`. You can assign it to an `Object[]` but that doesn't change its type, it's still a `String[]`.

If you want to do what you're trying to do (which is not good java programming, it is more reminiscent of script programming, because you're not using compile-time type checking) then you need to copy the array first to an `Object[]`

You can do that like this:

```
 String[] arr = text.split(",");
 Object[] row = Arrays.copyOf(arr, arr.length, Object[].class);
```